# Why do we need Hypothesis to build a model

Tags: parameters, regression, linear-regression, supervised-learning, linearmodels

Why do we need a hypothesis to build a model.? (In this case Linear Regression)
Instead, why don't we use a straight line equation to find the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

In linear regression you can test a lot of relationship between variables. For exemple parallelism od lines, line identity, independence of all variables, interpolation by polynomial function etc. According to what is tested built a model and compere models (for exemple full model vs model without interaction using the ANOVA).